# Cakephp 2.2.3 habtm saving to intermediary table

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many, save

Alright, so for my project in Cakephp 2.2.3, I setup my database and controllers and baked everything. I double checked it all and its all working (add, edit, delete). The one thing I cannot get working is saving to the intermediary table between the `users` table and a `websites` table. The intermediary table is `user_websites`. The `user_websites` table only has 3 fields: `id`, `user_id`, and `website_id`.

When I login as a registered user and go to the websites add page, I can add the website no problem, but it only saves to the `websites` table and nothing in the `user_websites` table. Fiddling with the add function in the `WebsitesController` I can get it to save the `website_id` in the `user_websites` table but again, nothing for the `user_id`. What I need to have happen, obviously, is when adding a new website it should save that record to the `websites` table, and add a record to the `user_websites` table with the current logged in user's id and the `website_id` that was just saved. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here's my code:

#### User Model

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'UserWebsite' => array(
    'className' => 'UserWebsite',
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
    'dependent' => false,
    'conditions' => '',
    'fields' => '',
    'order' => '',
    'limit' => '',
    'offset' => '',
    'exclusive' => '',
    'finderQuery' => '',
    'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

#### Website Model

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'UserWebsite' => array(
        'className' => 'UserWebsite',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);

public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'joinTable' => 'users_websites',
        'foreignKey' => 'website_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

#### UserWebsite Model

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Website' => array(
        'className' => 'Website',
        'foreignKey' => 'website_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

#### WebsitesController

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $this->Website->create();
        if ($this->Website->UserWebsite->saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true))) { 
    $log = $this->Website->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);
    debug($log);
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The website has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The website could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

And of course shortly after asking for help, I resolve the problem with the help of a buddy of mine. For anyone else who might need the answer or who may have better solutions here is what I added:

I just set the data's user_id to the current logged in user's id which is set in the beforeFilter of my AppController.

#### WebsitesController

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Website->create();

        // This is the line I added
        $this->request->data['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');

        if ($this->Website->UserWebsite->saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true))) { 
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The website has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The website could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are still not doing it quite the proper CakePHP way though.

It is currently only working because you defined a hasMany, which in this case is not the correct relation as you only need HABTM here.

Rename your table to:

```
users_websites
```

This is proper CakePHP and as you can see you actually defined it this way in your HABTM as well.

Now you can drop the hasMany and Cake should automatically save through HABTM and not through hasMany as you are doing now.

You would still need to do as you did though, since user_id isn't defined through your form/request you would always need to define it like you did.

Comment: You're correct, I misnamed my table as well as a few other things. I went ahead and changed it all to reflect the proper conventions. Would I need to leave: `if ($this->Website->UserWebsite->saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true)))` in as well? I tried it with the original `if ($this->Website->save($this->request->data))` and it doesn't work. It would be ideal if I could have it automatically save into the users_websites table by only supplying the user id; that way I don't have to change the the save line in the add function for every HABTM relationship.